# Why do packages export a non-exported function by returning the non-exported function through an exported function

Tags: go

Why do some packages declare two equal functions the only difference is one is exported and the other is not but the one that is exported just returns the non-exported function like this:

```
func Foo() {
    return foo()
}

func foo() {
   log.Println("Hello")
}
```

Why not just move the log into the exported function and get rid of the extra line? Obviously there is a reason but I don't really see one if you can just use the exported one everywhere. Thanks!

Example [here](https://github.com/yohcop/openid-go/blob/master/verify.go) of it being used in Production

Comment: Scientific Wild Assed Guessing here, but probably to make it easier to refactor in the future. If you decide later "You know, I'd rather have this function be exportable," then you just write `Foo` rather than refactor and change all the references to `foo` already in your code. Vice versa in the other direction.

Comment: What some examples of this? I have never seen this before.

Comment: Example [here](https://github.com/yohcop/openid-go/blob/master/verify.go) @CodingPickle

Comment: If that's the only example you know of, then I suggest asking the author. The author's email address is listed on their Github profile page.

Comment: In your example the two functions aren't equal.  `verify` takes in an additional `urlGetter` argument that local to the package, and which a client of the package doesn't have to construct or know anything about.

Comment: @CodingPickle you can also see another example [here](https://github.com/golang/oauth2/blob/master/oauth2.go) under staticTokenSource

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta see my other comment example. So you're saying so they can use an extra variable that's not exported or?

Comment: The second example allows you to control how clients construct certain objects. Clients have only one safe way to construct the object, using the constructor, and cannot directly do so via a struct literal. BTW you can link directly to lines of code in github: https://github.com/golang/oauth2/blob/master/oauth2.go#L259-L266

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta I'm on my phone :/ no option to do that on mobile

Comment: I'm saying the business logic of `verify` requires something that the client can't/shouldn't provide, so they are presented with the simpler `Verify` interface, and the package provides the `urlGetter` to the `verify` call.

Comment: @AmitKumarGupt ok so all in all you're saying you want to have better control over the non-exported function so you use an exported version that limits user input? If you wanna do a summary in an answer I'll mark it as answered

Comment: The StaticTokenSource example returns a composite literal. It does not invoke a function.

Comment: @CodingPickle but could the same not be done by just dropping the function and exporting the type and letting the end user just make a variable of that type by passing in a token?

Comment: Yes, but then the type is exported and the user can do anything with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mentioned a couple examples. The first example (https://github.com/yohcop/openid-go/blob/master/verify.go#L11-L13):

```
func Verify(uri string, cache DiscoveryCache, nonceStore NonceStore) (id string, err error) {
    return verify(uri, cache, urlGetter, nonceStore)
}
```

You can see that the unexported `verify` function takes an extra `urlGetter` argument.  This may be something that a client of this package cannot or should not provide.  The exported function determines how clients of the package can/should use it; the signature of the non-exported function reflects the dependencies required to do whatever business logic `verify` is doing.

The second example(https://github.com/golang/oauth2/blob/master/oauth2.go#L259-L266):

```
func StaticTokenSource(t *Token) TokenSource {
    return staticTokenSource{t}
}

// staticTokenSource is a TokenSource that always returns the same Token.
type staticTokenSource struct {
    t *Token
}
```

This restricts how clients can construct the `staticTokenSource`: there is only one way to do it, via the `StaticTokenSource` constructor, and it cannot be done directly via a struct literal. This can be useful for many reasons, e.g. input validation.  In this case, you want the safety of knowing that the client cannot mutate the `t` field on the object, and in order to do this, you leave the `t` field unexported.  But when it's unexported, the client will not be able to construct the struct literal directly, so you must provide a constructor.

In general, it makes your code much easier to reason about when you can restrict how things are accessed, constructed, or mutated.  Golang packages give you a nice mechanism to encapsulate modules of business logic.  It's a good idea to think about the conceptual components of your software, and what their interfaces should be.  What *really* needs to be exposed to client code consuming a given component?  Only things that really need to be exported should be.

Further reading: [Organizing Go code](https://blog.golang.org/organizing-go-code)

Comment: Thanks! Makes complete sense.